# Как дождаться завершения реализации onDraw после вызова invalidate()?

Tags: java, android-studio, canvas

Я постоянно передаю списки со значениями через цикл и вызываю `invalidate()`, и проблема в том, что `onDraw()` не успевает отрисовать предыдущее, как списки перезаписываются на новые значения и выдает ошибку:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 49, Size: 60
```

Как мне дождаться завершения реализации `onDraw()` после вызова `invalidate()`, прежде чем посылать новые значения?

```
while (true) {
                    values.clear();
                    intervals.clear();
                    for (float counter = 0; counter < 60; counter++) {
                        intervals.add(counter);
                        Random r = new Random();
                        value = r.nextInt(750);
                        values.add(value);
                    }
                    drawChart.CreateChart(values, intervals);

                }

protected void CreateChart(ArrayList<Integer> values, ArrayList<Float> intervals) {
            this.values = values;
            this.intervals = intervals;
            invalidate();
        }


   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);



        if (intervals.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
                canvas.drawLine(intervals.get(i-1) * 20, values.get(i - 1), intervals.get(i) * 20, values.get(i), mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
```